# Add http to a string - Convert it to a URL using PHP

Tags: php

I am building a site where I am asking users for Facebook and Twitter URL's but in typical user fashion I may just get a username i.e for Twitter `stackoverflow`.

I am looking to create a string for both facebook and twitter

So if the user typed `koodoocreative` for the Twitter string, I would convert it to...

> http://www.twitter.com/koodoocreative

Same with Facebook, I would essentially create the URL

> http://www.facebook.com/koodoocreative

Can I also check if the http:// has been added or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just simple `$twitter_url = 'http://www.twitter.com/'.$_POST['twitter'];`. You no need to convert.

Comment: Is there a way to check if the prefix also exists, Otherwise I'd be creating it twice? Sorry should have added to question

Comment: Could you give a example?

Comment: Sure... So a user that would read the request properly would already put in http://www.twitter.com/username So then converting it to a URL string would that not make the twitter_url variable : http://www.twitter.com/username/http://www.twitter/com/username ?

Comment: When asking for their Twitter / Facebook username, why don't you just ask for the username and stick the `http://www.facebook.com` / `http://www.twitter.com` on yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = 'www.twitter.com/koodoocreative';
```

#### First Way with `strpos`

```
if (strpos($url, 'http') === 0) 
{
    // http prefix not found
    $url = "http://" . $url; // http://www.twitter.com/koodoocreative
}
```

#### Another Way with `preg_match`:

```
if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url)) 
{
    // http prefix not found
    $url = "http://" . $url; // http://www.twitter.com/koodoocreative
}
```

Comment: Smart! That will do nicely, Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I would use the parse_url and http_build_url functions.

http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.parse-url.php

http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.http-build-url.php